# golang output templates

Tags: templates, go

how to display the contents of the template?

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "os"

)

func main() {
    t := template.New("another")
    t,e:=t.ParseFiles("test.html")
    if(e!=nil){
            fmt.Println(e);
    }
    t.Execute(os.Stdout, nil)

}
```

Why does not?
test.html exists

Comment: <b>text</b>
lala lalal ulalala

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to create a new template with `New` and then use `ParseFiles` on it. There is also a function `ParseFiles` which takes care of creating a new template behind the scenes.
Here is an example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    t, err := template.ParseFiles("test.html")
    if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err);
    }
    t.Execute(os.Stdout, nil)
}
```